# Traverse a JsonNode

Tags: java, json, stream, hashmap, jsonnode

This is how much JsonNode response has different key value pairs, similar to the example below. How can I traverse it to get the response in both key and value pair. Thank you.

````
{
    "message": "Results field contain api response",
    "results": {
        "Person 1": "USA",
        "Person 2": "India",
        "Name 3": "Europe",
        "People": "Germany"
    }
}```
````

Comment: Can you assume the structure of the data up front, or do you have to be able to read arbitrary structures?

Answer (score 0):

If you can assume the basic structure, where the top level is a map (JSONObject) that contains a 'message' key with a simple value, and a 'results' key with a value that is a collection of key/value pairs, then here's how to read the structure with `JSON.simple`:

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;

class Test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Reader reader = new FileReader("/tmp/test.json")) {
            JSONObject root = (JSONObject)(new JSONParser()).parse(reader);
            System.out.println("Message: " + root.get("message"));
            JSONObject results = (JSONObject) root.get("results");
            for (Object key: results.keySet())
                System.out.println(key + ": " + results.get(key));
        } catch (IOException | ParseException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Message: Results field contain api response
Person 1: USA
Person 2: India
People: Germany
Name 3: Europe
```

If you can't assume a specific structure, then you'd need to read the root and test its type.  Then, if it's a JSONObject, iterate over the keys and values in that object.  You'd then have to test the type of each value in the iteration to know what to do with that value.  You would keep going as deep as necessary to parse and process all the values in the structure.  If you need to allow for JSONArray values, you'd to the same thing with those, iterating over the values in the array, repeating the process on each value.  And so on and so on.  A recursive function works great here, where when you find a new JSONObject or JSONArray value, you call the same function you're in to process that sub-object.

Comment: @CrytoFool, I have a JsonNode as the response that I need stored in a List. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. PersonInfo class will contain getter and setter for person and country.

```
List<PersonInfo> listOfPersonInfos = new List<PersonInfo>();
result.get("results").fields().forEachRemaining(e -> {
                PersonInfo personInfo = new PersonInfo();
             
                personInfo.setCountry(e.getKey());
                personInfo.setName(e.getValue().textValue());
                listOfPersonInfos.add(personInfo);
            });
```